# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception in Java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am trying to initialize a 3D multidimensional array in Java, and assign 10001 to every value in it using three 'for-loops', but I am getting a error.

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6*

I need help in understanding what I am doing wrong in this.

```
    public static int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
        int[][][] dp = new int[prices.length][2][2]; // Intitialize 3D array 
        for(int i = 0; i<= prices.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k<= 2; k++){
                    dp[i][j][k] = 10001;
                }
            }
        }
```

I use two 'for-loops' for initializing and assigning values in 2D array. I am not able to understand why is the same not working for 3D arrays

Comment: change `<=` to `<`

Comment: You're accessing the 3rd element in a 2-element array.